# Magento custom admin page block layout issues

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

Hello I keep getting the following error when going to a admin page

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setSaveParametersInSession() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php on line 66

Here is my controller:

```
class LTS_Categorymove_Adminhtml_BlacklistController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action{

public function indexAction(){
    $this->loadLayout();

    var_dump(Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getUpdate()->getHandles());

    $this->renderLayout();
}

}
```

Here is my main block:

```
class LTS_Categorymove_Block_Adminhtml_Main extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container{

protected $_addButtonLabel = 'Add New Example';

public function __construct(){
    //error_log('fgboo');
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_main';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'categorymove';
    $this->_headerText = 'Blacklist';
    $this->_addButtonLabel = 'Button Here';
    parent::__construct();
}


protected function _prepareLayout(){
    $this->setChild( 'grid',
       $this->getLayout()->createBlock( $this->_blockGroup.'/' . $this->_controller . '_grid',
       $this->_controller . '.grid')->setSaveParametersInSession(true) );
   return parent::_prepareLayout();
}

}
```

Now when I have googled the issue everyone keeps saying its a incorect _controller declration but from reading around they say that i should be using the block name which I am. Any help would be awesome thanks

Comment: Try checking this [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/184145/).

Comment: yep hence if you see the code i have posted **$this->_controller = 'adminhtml_main';** I have seen that post and according to that post ni shouldent have a issue

Answer (score 2):

Check your folder structure one more time to make sure that all the files are located at correct path.

In my case for this issue the file was placed at wrong location. I placed the `Grid.php` in `controller/Adminhtml` folder rather than `Block/Adminhtml/<modulename>/Grid.php`